# Maximum value of trigonometric expression?

Tags: trigonometry

If $ f(x)  = \cos x ( \sin x + \sqrt [2] {\sin^2 x + \sin^2 \theta} )$, where $\theta $ is a given constant, then maximum value of $f (x) $ is?The answer is in terms of $\sin \theta$ or $\cos \theta $.

I tried expanding $ \cos \theta = \sqrt[2] {1 -  \sin^2\theta} $. I have no clue on how to proceed now. What should I do?

Comment: Did you try to cancel the derivative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

for example one case:Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$(\sin^2{x}+\sin^2{\theta}+\cos^2{x})(\cos^2{x}+\sin^2{x})\ge (\sqrt{\sin^2{x}+\sin^2{\theta}}|\cos{x}|+|\sin{x}\cos{x}|)^2\ge f^2(x)$$
so
$$f(x)\le \sqrt{(1+\sin^2{\theta})}$$

Comment: Thanks.But can you suggest me an alternate solution to this?

Comment: I have post alternate solution